# How to use switch case with nullable string (*string) in Golang?

Tags: go, switch-statement

Here is my code:

```
func ToSomething(arg *string) string {
    switch arg {
    case nil:
        return "something1"
    case "args1":
        return "something2"
    case "args2":
        return "something3"
    default:
        return "something4"
    }
}
```

It shows a red line under `args1` and `args2` that says

> Invalid case '"args1"' in switch on 'arg' (mismatched types 'string'
> and '*string')

anyone knows to use switch case with nullable string (*string) properly in golang?

Here is a go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/0TaeXSEIt06

Comment: Comparing a pointer to a string with a string is not going to work. You'll need to compare the dereferenced pointer's value.

Comment: I think thinking of pointers as "nullable strings" is the wrong mental model for pointers, and it's leading you towards some incorrect expectations for how comparisons between pointers and non-pointers work. Nullable types in other languages are not the same things as pointers, even though they may have similarities. A pointer contains an address to some other piece of memory, and you need to traverse *through* the pointer to reach the thing you want to perform comparisons on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `arg` is of type `*string`, you'd have to list values of `*string` in the `case` branches.

But! You obviously want to match the pointed `string` values, so listing `*string` values is not what you want: that checks for pointer equality.

So instead you should not use `arg` as the `switch` expression, but provide sensible conditions on the `case` branches like this:

```
func ToSomething(arg *string) string {
    switch {
    case arg == nil:
        return "something1"
    case *arg == "args1":
        return "something2"
    case *arg == "args2":
        return "something3"
    default:
        return "something4"
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
ptr := func(s string) *string { return &s }

fmt.Println(ToSomething(nil))
fmt.Println(ToSomething(ptr("args1")))
fmt.Println(ToSomething(ptr("args2")))
fmt.Println(ToSomething(ptr("xx")))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/2tFZP3cK4cb)):

```
something1
something2
something3
something4
```

Answer (score 2):

Each case must be the same type as `arg`. In your example, `arg` is `*string` and each case is `string`.

You could dereference `arg`:

```
func ToSomething(arg *string) string {
    if arg == nil {
        return "something1"
    }
    switch *arg {
    case "args1":
        return "something2"
    case "args2":
        return "something3"
    default:
        return "something4"
    }
}
```

Here is the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/WEZgwqT6qrQ).